# Invalid argument "class_mode" and in _make_train_function **self._function_kwargs)

Tags: keras, theano, keras-layer

I am working on some problems about machine learning and want to try the powerful package Keras(using Theano backend) in python. While I am running my code here https://github.com/mmkhajah/dkt, it gives me the follow errors messages:

```
 File "/home/nesrine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1214, in train_on_batch
self._make_train_function()


 File "/home/nesrine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 507, in _make_train_function
**self._function_kwargs)



File "/home/nesrine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1257, in function
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid argument "class_mode" passed to K.function with Theano backend
```

I don't know why it gave the error message, can anyone help me to fix the bug? Thank you .

Comment: You should include the source code that produces this error

Answer (score 0):

You've passed an extra argument `class_mode="binary"` to `model.compile()`. This argument will be passed into `K.function` with Theano backend. You can just remove it to get past this error.

According to the documentation of `compile`:

> **kwargs: When using the Theano/CNTK backends, these arguments are passed into `K.function`. When using the TensorFlow backend, these arguments are passed into `tf.Session.run`.